# Premiere export settings for background video

Tags: background, export, html5-video, adobe-premiere

I'm not sure if it's allowed ask these questions here, but looks important for us webdevelopers (even bad dev like me :p ).

The question is about export setting videons on Premiere. I'm looking for a background video 30s like airbnb or paypal. Yesterday, I check paypal size and it's only 10/15 Mb for more than a minute. How did they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you want a low average bit rate. Things that can help with that are: keep the resolution low (you can scale it up a bit on the client); use H.264 High Profile (for the H.264 version); use 2-pass encoding; use variable bit rate. You can try increasing the GOP length too.

I assume there's no audio, so that shouldn't be an issue. (Can't remember if Adobe has an option for no sound track, but you can set the audio to a very low bit rate, or post-process it with ffmpeg or something to remove the audio track.)

If you have any control over the video content, you can try to keep it compressible. For example, avoid video with lots of detail or rapid motion. You might be able to selectively blur parts in a way that doesn't look bad. If it doesn't move too fast, you might be able to decrease the frame rate.

If you really want to optimize, you'll probably need to experiment a lot.